# Why does Boolean.class.newInstance() throw exception?

Tags: java

I think the sunject's pretty self-explanatory. I use JDK 1.6.0 update 26, and created a new project with just one line to confirm this:

```
Boolean.class.newInstance();
```

and it throws the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Boolean
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
```

Does it suppose to fail? If so, why?

Comment: Of course try to create another Boolean is pointless since every possible Boolean is already defined i.e. TRUE and FALSE, with autoboxing you can just do `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a class you can find out what it needs to be constructed:

```
Class cl = // initialize somehow
// get all constructors for class
Constructor[] constructors = cl.getConstructors(); 

 // for each constructor
for(Constructor c : constructors)
{
     // if there is a zero-parameter constructor
    if(c.getParameterTypes().length == 0)
    {
        // then we can safely create a constructor for it
        cl.newInstance(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

The `Boolean` class has two constructors, both take one argument. Calling `Boolean.class.newInstance()` is trying to call a zero-arg constructor that doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't do much Java, mainly C++, and I never realized this - are you saying that in Java calling a non-existing function is a _runtime_ error, not a _compile time_ error? Fascinating.

Comment: @Kerrek it is a compile-time error if you are writing the code to call the constructor directly. The question involves the Java Reflection API which allows you to call methods, constructors etc. dynamically. Since the call targets are not known at compile time, the only possible error is a runtime error.

Comment: But in actual code I don't actually know it's boolean, I work with generics and class passed via variable. How do I create an instance of any class given as a variable then?

Comment: @golergka - you can only do that if you know the set of available constructors for the class you are trying to instantiate. Not all classes have a zero-arg constructor. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a generic data structure which creates it's children. However, I already decided to clone them from provided default instance rather than instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

The `Boolean` class has two different constructors. Both of them take one argument. One of them takes a `boolean` itself but the other takes a `String`. If the string is NOT empty when you pass it to the `Boolean` class, it will be recognized as setting the `Boolean` to `true`. If it is null or contains nothing, then it is `false`.